# Fileupload with CMIS + Apache fails due to "Proxy Error"

Tags: apache, cmis, opencmis, dotcmis, cmis-workbench

We developed a web application which uses opencmis and a windows client which uses dotcmis. The web application runs behind an apache httpd.

We are facing the following problem:
Small files can be uploaded by the client without problems (< 1,5 gigabytes). 
However, if we try to upload larger files, we get a "Proxy Error". The stacktrace does not give any more information.
We also tried to upload via cmis workbench with the same result...

Are there any configuration parameters for apache we maybe overlooked? Or do you think the problem should be searched elsewhere?

EDIT: I should mention, that the file is uploaded completely nevertheless. And also: We tried disable apache, connect via http instead of https and upload a file and it works perfectly.

EDIT2: We found a solution, although it does not seem to be a very good one... We set the following configuration entries in httpd.conf:
**Timeout=500** and **ProxyTimeout=500**. Default value is 60 for these entries.
This solved the problem. However, it would be nice to know, why this problem occures in the first place.

Greets

Comment: Did you check both the Apache HTTPD and CMIS Server logs?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately both logs do not give us any information. The error does not even appear in these logfiles.

Comment: Maybe set the Apache log level to debug and see then?

Comment: Already did that. See my edit for further details.